# Validation fails on update, form keeps going to create method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Goal: Update existing records with a modal without needing  to link_to a new page.

Issue: I assume my issue is that I am unable to identify the exact record on the page with the form because I can't know this until the form is submitted.

**ShopProduct Controller:**

```
  def new
    @shop_product = ShopProduct.new
  end

  def create
    @shop_product = ShopProduct.new(shop_product_params)
    @shop = Shop.find_by(params[:shop_id])
    product = Product.find_by(params[:product_id])
    @shop_product.product_id = product.id
    @shop_product.shop_id = @shop.id

      if @shop_product.save!
        redirect_to '/'
        flash[:notice] = "saved"
      else
        redirect_to '/'
        flash[:notice] = "no saved"
      end
  end

  def update
    @shop_product = ShopProduct.find_by(store_variant_id: params[:store_variant_id])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @shop_product.update_attributes!(product_id: params[:product_id], sync: params[:sync])

        format.html { redirect_to @shop_product, notice: 'Shop product was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @shop_product }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @shop_product.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Aside from linkingto a new page, I can only think of defining directly on the

I load the form from this ShopDashboardController:

```
  def product_variants
    @shop = Shop.find(params[:shop_id])
    session = ShopifyAPI::Session.new(domain: @shop.shopify_domain, token: @shop.shopify_token, api_version: '2019-04')
    ShopifyAPI::Base.activate_session(session)
    @in_store_products = ShopifyAPI::Product.find(:all)
    @in_store_product = ShopifyAPI::Product.find(params[:shopify_product_id])
    @in_store_variants = ShopifyAPI::Variant.find(:all, params: { product_id: params[:shopify_product_id]})
    @shop_products = ShopProduct.where(shop_id: @shop)
    @products = Product.all
    @shop_product = ShopProduct.find_or_create_by(store_variant_id: params[:store_variant_id])
  end
```

Now, as mentioned above, the only unique record for any ShopProduct is the id and the store_variant_id... If i use `find_by` in the `def product_variants`, the page won't load due to not being able to identify the @shop_product.  I am unable to pass those params through because there may be multiple store_variant_ids, so I pass the Shop.id and ShopProduct.store_product_id only.  But the store_product_id isn't a unique identifier as multiple records can have the same one.  The only unique records are the id and store_variant_id.

**Form (the `variant` is from a do loop):**

```
<% @in_store_variants.each do |variant| %>
    ...
    <%= form_for @shop_product do |f| %>
      <%= f.collection_select :product_id, @products, :id, :sku %>
      <%= f.hidden_field :store_product_id, value: variant.product_id %>
      <%= f.hidden_field :store_variant_id, value: variant.id %>
      <%= f.hidden_field :shop_id, value: @shop.id %>
      <%= f.hidden_field :sync, value: true %>
      <%= f.submit "Sync" %>
    ...
<% end %>
```

I am able to create new records only.

When i use the form again to update I get:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid (Validation failed: Store variant has already been taken):
app/controllers/shop_products_controller.rb:61:in `create'
```

Model ShopProduct:

```
  belongs_to :product
  has_one :shop
  has_one :order
  validates :store_variant_id, uniqueness: true, on: :create
```

If the record exists, shouldn't it update? Or is there something I am missing here?

It is possible to pursue my goal with rails/ruby alone or is javascript needed?

**UPDATE:**

I tried defining the ShopProduct on the front-end like so:

```
<% @in_store_variants.each do |variant| %>
    <% shop_product = @shop_products.find_by(store_variant_id: variant.id)  %>
<%= form_for shop_product do |f| %>
  <%= f.collection_select :product_id, @products, :id, :sku %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :store_product_id, value: variant.product_id %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :store_variant_id, value: variant.id %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :shop_id, value: @shop.id %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :sync, value: true %>
  <%= f.submit "Sync" %>
<% end %>
```

When submitting:

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"gaMboYCSE8v63TVzmgx4pZDMhoz205f1MV+VMhmFA/WWhVh5Pcu6u/qayU8lDmjeRXw==", "shop_product"=>{"product_id"=>"1", "store_product_id"=>"1965345", "store_variant_id"=>"19364273", "shop_id"=>"1", "sync"=>"true"}, "commit"=>"Sync", "id"=>"12"}
```

**Error:**

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `update' for nil:NilClass):
```

**or with update attributes:**

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `update_attributes!' for nil:NilClass):
```

If it's finding it, shouldn't it be working? The param is being passed

Answer (score 0):

It's because that form only caters the `create` action. Usually, if you need to update a `resource`, you go to `/shop_products/:id/edit`.

But if you really wanted to reuse that form, it's a little bit complicated adding more conditions, but what you want is to send a `PUT` request to `/shop_products/:id` and it would call the `#update` action of your controller. A form, by default, sends a `POST` request so consider that.

Comment: Right but I want to be able to do all of this from a modal without needing to go to a new page.

Comment: From my understanding.  The form caters to update and create.  If it exists, it's supposed to update.  If it doesn't exist, it's supposed to create.  I added an update to the bottom of the Post as a short term solution which sends the update method but it won't update saying its nil.

Comment: Not in that context, the reason it only caters `create` is because your `@shop_product` is not a persisted record since in the `#new` action, you've initialized it as new i.e.  `@shop_product = ShopProduct.new`

Comment: If you want your form to be smart, you need to involve javascript into the page.

Comment: Using javascript in what context?